# Wordpress wp_nav_menu add an element to container

Tags: wordpress

Would someone like to help me? How can I add a div to a wp_nav_menu container from:

```
<nav id="my-menu"><ul><li>...[menu-items]...</li></ul></nav>
```

to:

```
<nav id="my-menu"><div class="additional-element"></div><ul><li>...[menu-items]...</li></ul></nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

Just put other args you need in the array, you can check them in, [`wp_nav_menu()` page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

```
<nav id="my-menu">
    <div class="additional-element"></div>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container' => false
    )); ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks @Marcos for your response. Actually i've many menu and setting page on dashboard which is dtermine what menu i need to add that div element. I've try extending Walker_Nav_Menu and rewrite start_lvl method. But it make each ul item add that div. I need to add just one div element right after menu container.

Comment: wait, are you trying to put this menu as a backend menu? on WP dashboard or in the front-end?

Comment: In front-end. I need regsitered menu can be meodified like my question above depend on my setting page at backend.